# How do you close WebSocketContainer / WebSocketClient / Jetty client in Java?

Tags: java, jetty, java-websocket

I'm trying to use the Jetty's WebSocket client, but the application would just stuck there and won't exit. There is nothing fancy about it...

```
public class TestEndPoint extends Endpoint {
    private Session sess;

    public TestEndPoint(URI endpoint) throws Exception {

        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        container.connectToServer(this, endpoint);
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            this.sess.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I am connecting that to my PHP Ratchet WS, nothing special, no special logic, I just print out `open` when a client connects and `close` when client disconnects.

Then I run it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        TestEndPoint test = new TestEndPoint(new URI("ws://localhost:8080/test"));
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        test.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I can see that my WS would print "close", but then the Java application would never exit. so I took a thread dump and see that the `jetty` stuff is stuck there in some `QueuedThreadPool`...

Some of the thread dump:

```
"WebSocketContainer@1735934726-15" #15 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000016cdf000 nid=0x1c5c runnable [0x000000001763e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:296)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:278)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:159)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x00000000ebf678c8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
    - locked <0x00000000ebf68128> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000ebf67d40> (a sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.select(ManagedSelector.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"WebSocketContainer@1735934726-14" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000016cc7000 nid=0xfb4 waiting on condition [0x000000001753f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000ebde1df8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(BlockingArrayQueue.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll(QueuedThreadPool.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$800(QueuedThreadPool.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:634)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Finally, I'm using these version of `Jetty` in my Gradle;

```
compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket', name: 'websocket-api', version: '9.4.6.v20170531'
compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket', name: 'websocket-client', version: '9.4.6.v20170531'
compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket', name: 'javax-websocket-client-impl', version: '9.4.7.v20170914'
```

What's the right way to close a web-socket or client?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After much Googling and looking around many sample code, it looks like you need to manually `stop` the `WebSocketContainer` by casting it to the `org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle`!

In order to stop the Jetty's WebSocket Client, you need to do the following, either via the `Session` or the `WebSocketContainer` itself. So in my `close` function:

```
try {
    Session sess = getSession();
    WebSocketContainer container = sess.getContainer();

    // Need to cast the container to Jetty's LifeCycle
    if(container != null && container instanceof LifeCycle) { 
        Logger.debug("Stopping Jetty's WebSocket Client");
        ((LifeCycle) container).stop(); 
    }

    sess.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Logger.error(e);
}
```

There is **no documentation** on this what-so-ever on Jetty's website either (http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.7.v20170914/)

Comment: This is helpful. This prevents leak of LocalEndpoint objects and daemon threads

Comment: Glad this helped someone after 2 years!! :)